# How do I serialize/deserialize Json *no named* arrays using Json.NET or other serializer

Tags: json, json.net

I'm using Json.NET (also tried DataContractJsonSerializer) but I just can't figure out how to deal with no named arrays when serializing/deserialising?

My c# classes look something like this:

```
public class Subheading
{
    public IList<Column> columns { get; set; }

    public Subheading()
    {
        Columns = new List<Column>();
    }

}

public class Column
{
    public IList<Link> links { get; set; }

    public Column()
    {
        Links = new List<Link>();
    }

}

public class Link
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }

}
```

The Json being generated is something like this:

```
{
          "columns": [
            {
              "**links**": [
                {
                  "label": "New Releases",
                  "url": "/usa/collections/sun/newreleases"
                },
               ...
              ]
            },
           ]
    ...
}
```

How do I do to loose the "links" to make it like this?:

```
{
      "columns": [
          [
            {
              "label": "New Releases",
              "url": "/usa/collections/sun/newreleases"
            },
           ...
          ],
          ...
      ]
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is a custom `JsonConverter`. Your code should look like this:

```
class SubheadingJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // tell Newtonsoft that this class can only convert Subheading objects
        return objectType == typeof(Subheading);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // you expect an array in your JSON, so deserialize a list and
        // create a Subheading using the deserialized result
        var columns = serializer.Deserialize<List<Column>>(reader);

        return new Subheading { column = columns };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // when serializing "value", just serialize its columns
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ((Subheading) value).columns);
    }
}
```

Then you have to decorate your `Subheading` class with a `JsonConverterAttribute`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SubheadingJsonConverter)]
public class Subheading
{
    // ...
}
```